# How to make this SQL in LINQ to SQL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

I'm familiar with the way SQL works but working with LINQ to SQL gives me an headache. I've the following query but I not able to change it to LINQ to SQL. Can someone help me with this query or explain me how to work this on out?

```
 SELECT
         DISTINCT Pr.Pcode_,
         Pr.Omschrijving,
         Pt.TypeOmschr 
    FROM 
        Projecten AS Pr
    INNER JOIN 
        ProjectTypen AS Pt 
        ON Pr.ProjType_ = Pt.TypeID 
        AND
        Pr.Status NOT IN ( 'Afgerond', 'Afgewezen' ) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Personeel AS Pe
        ON Pr.SeniorId_ = Pe.PerId_ 
        OR 
        Pr.CorId_ = Pe.PerId_
        WHERE  
        ( Pe.Naam LIKE '%%' ) 
         OR  
        ( Pr.Omschrijving LIKE '%%' ) 
        OR
        ( Pr.Pcode_ LIKE '%%' ) 
        OR 
       ( Pt.TypeOmschr LIKE '%%' )
        ORDER  BY 
        Pr.Pcode_
```

**Edit:**
I have the following L2S but it is not working. I'm getting the following error: *The name 'Pe' is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'.* I guess the problem is the left join, but what is the solution?

```
    from Pr in _db.Projectens  
    join Pt in _db.ProjectTypens on Pr.ProjType_ equals Pt.TypeID  
    join Pe in _db.Personeels on ((Pr.SeniorId_ == Pe.PerId_) || (Pr.SeniorId_ == Pe.PerId_)) into P  
    where Pr.Pcode_.Contains(search) || Pr.Omschrijving.Contains(search) || Pt.TypeOmschr.Contains(search) || Pe.Naam.Contains(search)  
    select new SearchProjectViewModel {  
        ProjectCode = Pr.Pcode_,  
        ProjectName = Pr.Omschrijving,  
        ProjectType = Pt.TypeOmschr  
    };
```

Comment: do you want to convert this SQL to Linq?

Comment: I've tried this `from Pr in _db.Projectens
                    join Pt in _db.ProjectTypens on Pr.ProjType_ equals Pt.TypeID 
                    join Pe in _db.Personeels on ((Pr.SeniorId_ == Pe.PerId_) || Pr.SeniorId_ == Pe.PerId_) into P
                    select new {...};`

But it's of course a possibility to make a stored procedure, but i'd like to learn the LINQ to SQL syntax..

Comment: @GiedoDonkers looks to me like your L2S is almost right, apart from a missing `where` clause before your select - something like `where Pe.Naam != null || Pr.Omschrivijving != null || ....` (I think I'm right in thinking that your `LIKE` statements are just checking for strings?  If not you might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835790/how-to-do-sql-like-in-linq)

Comment: @AndrasZoltan thank you for the link. I've got this now `from Pr in _db.Projectens join Pt in _db.ProjectTypens on Pr.ProjType_ equals Pt.TypeID join Pe in _db.Personeels on ((Pr.SeniorId_ == Pe.PerId_) || Pr.SeniorId_ == Pe.PerId_) into P where Pr.Pcode_.Contains(search) || Pr.Omschrijving.Contains(search) || Pt.TypeOmschr.Contains(search) || Pe.Naam.Contains(search) select new SearchProjectViewModel { ProjectCode = Pr.Pcode_, ProjectName = Pr.Omschrijving, ProjectType = Pt.TypeOmschr };` but I'm getting the error _The name 'Pe' is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'._ What is wrong?

Comment: @GiedoDonkers I'm not sure although you're using `==` for the `join Pe` when it should be `equals`. Also I think it would now be a great idea to update your question, adding at the end that linq code you've just put in that comment; I think you might get a bit more attention once you've done that :)

Comment: @GiedoDonkers - much better, if I could rescind my 'close' vote I would

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
join Pe in _db.Personeels on ((Pr.SeniorId_ == Pe.PerId_) || (Pr.SeniorId_ == Pe.PerId_)) into P
```

should be

```
join Pe in _db.Personeels on ((Pr.SeniorId_ equals Pe.PerId_) || (Pr.SeniorId_ equals Pe.PerId_)) into P
```

try and let me know, if this works.

Comment: I've tried that before but unfortunately that doesn't work, thanks for trying.